# How to set multiple window owners in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

I know it's probably not possible, but that is the best way to describe the resulting effect. I need to make a window always on top of a certain set of other windows, much in the same way that a child window will always stay on top of its parent. The thing is, now I want to have multiple "parents". How do I do that? I know it's possible since the GIMP application does it with its toolbox.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setAlwaysOnTop-boolean- ?

Comment: that's not good tho, I only want it to be "always on top" of a specific set of windows, not all windows from all applications.